# Tutorial for SecurityCritical SecurityTransparent and new .NET 4 feature: Level 2

Tags: appsec, source-code, .net

I need a primer for both the legacy (Level 1) .NET 2.0 security attributes and the new .NET 4 (Level 2) ones.

I'm not familiar with the implications of controlling LinkDemand, stack walks, unverifiable code and other [items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648462.aspx#pagguidelines0003_aptca2) in this Patern and Practices guide.

Where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 4):

Until someone can point you at a comprehensive resource, you may want to take a look at [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125172817/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnfa/).

For example, it has a article about marking your code transparent ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160125172817/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnfa/)/archive/2005/09/09/462975.aspx).